# Decoding base64 string doesn't work in JS, works with Linux' base64

Tags: javascript, base64, decoding

I have a Playready DRM manifest and am extracting the base64 encoded header from it, this part works fine.

However, when I try to decode the string in Javascript (client-side) via either `atob` or one of the other copy-paste implementations provided around here, there's a blank missing-character square between each expected character.

If I pipe the encoded string into `base64 --decode` in a terminal, I get the expected output.

Base64 encoded string: `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`

`base64 -decode` output: `��<WRMHEADER xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader" version="4.0.0.0"><DATA><PROTECTINFO><KEYLEN>16</KEYLEN><ALGID>AESCTR</ALGID></PROTECTINFO><KID>1itH2Ri0skW/V7ugYh/4hg==</KID><CHECKSUM>hu6NSdg4X2U=</CHECKSUM><LA_URL>https://lic.staging.drmtoday.com/license-proxy-headerauth/drmtoday/RightsManager.asmx</LA_URL></DATA></WRMHEADER>`

Javascript output: `҂����Ȃ<�W�R�M�H�E�A�D�E�R� �x�m�l�n�s�=�"�h�t�t�p�:�/�/�s�c�h�e�m�a�s�.�m�i�c�r�o�s�o�f�t�.�c�o�m�/�D�R�M�/�2�0�0�7�/�0�3�/�P�l�a�y�R�e�a�d�y�H�e�a�d�e�r�"� �v�e�r�s�i�o�n�=�"�4�.�0�.�0�.�0�"�>�<�D�A�T�A�>�<�P�R�O�T�E�C�T�I�N�F�O�>�<�K�E�Y�L�E�N�>�1�6�<�/�K�E�Y�L�E�N�>�<�A�L�G�I�D�>�A�E�S�C�T�R�<�/�A�L�G�I�D�>�<�/�P�R�O�T�E�C�T�I�N�F�O�>�<�K�I�D�>�1�i�t�H�2�R�i�0�s�k�W�/�V�7�u�g�Y�h�/�4�h�g�=�=�<�/�K�I�D�>�<�C�H�E�C�K�S�U�M�>�h�u�6�N�S�d�g�4�X�2�U�=�<�/�C�H�E�C�K�S�U�M�>�<�L�A�_�U�R�L�>�h�t�t�p�s�:�/�/�l�i�c�.�s�t�a�g�i�n�g�.�d�r�m�t�o�d�a�y�.�c�o�m�/�l�i�c�e�n�s�e�-�p�r�o�x�y�-�h�e�a�d�e�r�a�u�t�h�/�d�r�m�t�o�d�a�y�/�R�i�g�h�t�s�M�a�n�a�g�e�r�.�a�s�m�x�<�/�L�A�_�U�R�L�>�<�/�D�A�T�A�>�<�/�W�R�M�H�E�A�D�E�R�>�`

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to combat this? I assume it's the character set, but trying others yields similar results.

**EDIT**
SO has displayed the *Javascript output* string properly (i.e. How it should be in my program) so perhaps I'm not escaping it properly or something? Here's how the editor showed it to me when I pasted it in the first time: [image: JS Output]

**EDIT 2**
After the first edit, SO is now showing the wierd characters again...

Comment: Sounds like it's UTF-16 encoded, did you try that?  This question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592364/utf-16-to-utf-8-conversion-in-javascript

Comment: @JeffUK You were right! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data seems to be encoded UTF-16 with BOM.
Using function found in [UTF-16 to UTF-8 conversion in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592364/utf-16-to-utf-8-conversion-in-javascript) it seems you could have your data in UTF-8 / ASCII using

```
decodeUTF16LE(atob(yourString)).slice(5) // .slice(5) = remove BOM
```