# d3-fetch and UTF-16 LE

Tags: d3.js, promise, fetch-api, utf-16

I have large volumes of data, pipe delimited text files, that Im loading into d3. The volume of data is large enough that I have split the files into many 10,000 line files.  Previously, I was able to us d3.queue + d3.text() and then concatenate then into on string which I then passed with d3.dsv. Like so:

```
d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.text, "/data/headers.txt")
    .defer(d3.text, "/data/batch1.txt")
    .defer(d3.text, "/data/batch2.txt")
    .await(function(error, file1, file2, file3) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Oh dear, something went wrong: ' + error);
        } else {
            var allData = file1 + file2 + file3;
            var psv = d3.dsvFormat("|");
            var parsedData = psv.parse(allData);
        }
    });
```

This worked well, but d3.queue has been removed and d3.text is now underpinned by Promises and fetch (https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md). Loading multiple files is done with promises.all.

```
Promise.all([
        d3.text('/data/out1.csv'),
        d3.text('/data/batch1.csv'),
        d3.text('/data/batch2.csv')
    ])
    .then((vals) => {
        let allData;
        vals.forEach(d => {
            allData = allData + d;
        });
        var psv = d3.dsvFormat("|");
        var parsedData = psv.parse(allData);
    });
```

This seems to be working, but now I am having an encoding issue that I did not have before since it turns out these data are in UTF-16 LE ( i think). The previous version of d3.text() handled the encoding, but now I've got these - �� - showing up all over the place and line endings are not being parsed properly resulting every other row of the resulting data containing all "undefined" values.

After some digging I am trying to pass an init objectr to fetch:

```
d3.text("/data/headers.csv", { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/html, charset=UTF-16" } }).then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

But its not making a difference. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution? can't believe after all these years, steps to load a CSV file with special characters or utf-16 format has not been documentated

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the UTF-16LE to Unicode.

I found a small function https://stackoverflow.com/a/14601808/9938317

Comment: Thanks! Still getting this though:

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
    at