# Submitting an OTP to Microsoft API with RSA encryption

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, encryption, rsa

I'm gonna keep this short and clean.

I need to submit an OTP to Microsoft's API. This OTP however, is encrypted on the client side with some JavaScript function and then submitted to the API. That's the Microsoft's script for encryption (the original script has over 2000 lines, I only left functions used by `Encrypt()` function. I believe it is just plain RSA encryption in JavaScript but I could be wrong):

```js
function Encrypt(e, t, i, r) {
  var n = [];
  switch (i.toLowerCase()) {
  case "saproof":
      if (null == t) {
          return null
      }
      n = PackageSADataForProof(t);
      break;
  case "newpwd":
      if (null == r) {
          return null
      }
  }
  if (null == n || "undefined" == typeof n) {
      return n
  }
  if ("undefined" != typeof Key && void 0 !== parseRSAKeyFromString) {
      var o = parseRSAKeyFromString(Key)
  }
  var s = RSAEncrypt(n, o, randomNum);
  return s
}

function PackageSADataForProof(e) {
  var t, i = [], r = 0;
  for (t = 0; t < e.length; t++) {
      i[r++] = 127 & e.charCodeAt(t),
      i[r++] = (65280 & e.charCodeAt(t)) >> 8
  }
  return i
}

function parseRSAKeyFromString(e) {
  var t = e.indexOf(";");
  if (0 > t) {
      return null
  }
  var i = e.substr(0, t)
    , r = e.substr(t + 1)
    , n = i.indexOf("=");
  if (0 > n) {
      return null
  }
  var o = i.substr(n + 1);
  if (n = r.indexOf("="),
  0 > n) {
      return null
  }
  var s = r.substr(n + 1)
    , a = new Object;
  return a.n = hexStringToMP(s),
  a.e = parseInt(o, 16),
  a
}

function hexStringToMP(e) {
  var t, i, r = Math.ceil(e.length / 4), n = new JSMPnumber;
  for (n.size = r,
  t = 0; r > t; t++) {
      i = e.substr(4 * t, 4),
      n.data[r - 1 - t] = parseInt(i, 16)
  }
  return n
}

function RSAEncrypt(e, t) {
  for (var i = [], r = 42, n = 2 * t.n.size - r, o = 0; o < e.length; o += n) {
      if (o + n >= e.length) {
          var s = RSAEncryptBlock(e.slice(o), t, randomNum);
          s && (i = s.concat(i))
      } else {
          var s = RSAEncryptBlock(e.slice(o, o + n), t, randomNum);
          s && (i = s.concat(i))
      }
  }
  var a = byteArrayToBase64(i);
  return a
}

function RSAEncryptBlock(e, t, i) {
  var r = t.n
    , n = t.e
    , o = e.length
    , s = 2 * r.size
    , a = 42;
  if (o + a > s) {
      return null
  }
  applyPKCSv2Padding(e, s, i),
  e = e.reverse();
  var l = byteArrayToMP(e)
    , d = modularExp(l, n, r);
  d.size = r.size;
  var h = mpToByteArray(d);
  return h = h.reverse()
}

function JSMPnumber() {
  this.size = 1,
  this.data = [],
  this.data[0] = 0
}

function byteArrayToMP(e) {
  var t = new JSMPnumber
    , i = 0
    , r = e.length
    , n = r >> 1;
  for (i = 0; n > i; i++) {
      t.data[i] = e[2 * i] + (e[1 + 2 * i] << 8)
  }
  return r % 2 && (t.data[i++] = e[r - 1]),
  t.size = i,
  t
}

function modularExp(e, t, i) {
  for (var r = [], n = 0; t > 0; ) {
      r[n] = 1 & t,
      t >>>= 1,
      n++
  }
  for (var o = duplicateMP(e), s = n - 2; s >= 0; s--) {
      o = modularMultiply(o, o, i),
      1 == r[s] && (o = modularMultiply(o, e, i))
  }
  return o
}
function modularMultiply(e, t, i) {
  var r = multiplyMP(e, t)
    , n = divideMP(r, i);
  return n.r
}
function multiplyMP(e, t) {
  var i = new JSMPnumber;
  i.size = e.size + t.size;
  var r, n;
  for (r = 0; r < i.size; r++) {
      i.data[r] = 0
  }
  var o = e.data
    , s = t.data
    , a = i.data;
  if (e == t) {
      for (r = 0; r < e.size; r++) {
          a[2 * r] += o[r] * o[r]
      }
      for (r = 1; r < e.size; r++) {
          for (n = 0; r > n; n++) {
              a[r + n] += 2 * o[r] * o[n]
          }
      }
  } else {
      for (r = 0; r < e.size; r++) {
          for (n = 0; n < t.size; n++) {
              a[r + n] += o[r] * s[n]
          }
      }
  }
  return normalizeJSMP(i),
  i
}
function normalizeJSMP(e) {
  var t, i, r, n, o;
  for (r = e.size,
  i = 0,
  t = 0; r > t; t++) {
      n = e.data[t],
      n += i,
      o = n,
      i = Math.floor(n / 65536),
      n -= 65536 * i,
      e.data[t] = n
  }
}
function removeLeadingZeroes(e) {
  for (var t = e.size - 1; t > 0 && 0 == e.data[t--]; ) {
      e.size--
  }
}
function divideMP(e, t) {
  var i = e.size
    , r = t.size
    , n = t.data[r - 1]
    , o = t.data[r - 1] + t.data[r - 2] / 65536
    , s = new JSMPnumber;
  s.size = i - r + 1,
  e.data[i] = 0;
  for (var a = i - 1; a >= r - 1; a--) {
      var l = a - r + 1
        , d = Math.floor((65536 * e.data[a + 1] + e.data[a]) / o);
      if (d > 0) {
          var h = multiplyAndSubtract(e, d, t, l);
          for (0 > h && (d--,
          multiplyAndSubtract(e, d, t, l)); h > 0 && e.data[a] >= n; ) {
              h = multiplyAndSubtract(e, 1, t, l),
              h > 0 && d++
          }
      }
      s.data[l] = d
  }
  removeLeadingZeroes(e);
  var u = {
      "q": s,
      "r": e
  };
  return u
}
function multiplyAndSubtract(e, t, i, r) {
  var n, o = e.data.slice(0), s = 0, a = e.data;
  for (n = 0; n < i.size; n++) {
      var l = s + i.data[n] * t;
      s = l >>> 16,
      l -= 65536 * s,
      l > a[n + r] ? (a[n + r] += 65536 - l,
      s++) : a[n + r] -= l
  }
  return s > 0 && (a[n + r] -= s),
  a[n + r] < 0 ? (e.data = o.slice(0),
  -1) : 1
}
function applyPKCSv2Padding(e, t, i) {
  var r, n = e.length, o = [218, 57, 163, 238, 94, 107, 75, 13, 50, 85, 191, 239, 149, 96, 24, 144, 175, 216, 7, 9], s = t - n - 40 - 2, a = [];
  for (r = 0; s > r; r++) {
      a[r] = 0
  }
  a[s] = 1;
  var l = o.concat(a, e)
    , d = [];
  for (r = 0; 20 > r; r++) {
      d[r] = Math.floor(256 * Math.random())
  }
  d = SHA1(d.concat(i));
  var h = MGF(d, t - 21)
    , u = XORarrays(l, h)
    , c = MGF(u, 20)
    , p = XORarrays(d, c)
    , f = [];
  for (f[0] = 0,
  f = f.concat(p, u),
  r = 0; r < f.length; r++) {
      e[r] = f[r]
  }
}
function MGF(e, t) {
  if (t > 4096) {
      return null
  }
  var i = e.slice(0)
    , r = i.length;
  i[r++] = 0,
  i[r++] = 0,
  i[r++] = 0,
  i[r] = 0;
  for (var n = 0, o = []; o.length < t; ) {
      i[r] = n++,
      o = o.concat(SHA1(i))
  }
  return o.slice(0, t)
}
function XORarrays(e, t) {
  if (e.length != t.length) {
      return null
  }
  for (var i = [], r = e.length, n = 0; r > n; n++) {
      i[n] = e[n] ^ t[n]
  }
  return i
}
function SHA1(e) {
  var t, i = e.slice(0);
  PadSHA1Input(i);
  var r = {
      "A": 1732584193,
      "B": 4023233417,
      "C": 2562383102,
      "D": 271733878,
      "E": 3285377520
  };
  for (t = 0; t < i.length; t += 64) {
      SHA1RoundFunction(r, i, t)
  }
  var n = [];
  return wordToBytes(r.A, n, 0),
  wordToBytes(r.B, n, 4),
  wordToBytes(r.C, n, 8),
  wordToBytes(r.D, n, 12),
  wordToBytes(r.E, n, 16),
  n
}
function wordToBytes(e, t, i) {
  var r;
  for (r = 3; r >= 0; r--) {
      t[i + r] = 255 & e,
      e >>>= 8
  }
}
function PadSHA1Input(e) {
  var t, i = e.length, r = i, n = i % 64, o = 55 > n ? 56 : 120;
  for (e[r++] = 128,
  t = n + 1; o > t; t++) {
      e[r++] = 0
  }
  var s = 8 * i;
  for (t = 1; 8 > t; t++) {
      e[r + 8 - t] = 255 & s,
      s >>>= 8
  }
}

function SHA1RoundFunction(e, t, i) {
  var r, n, o, s = 1518500249, a = 1859775393, l = 2400959708, d = 3395469782, h = [], u = e.A, c = e.B, p = e.C, f = e.D, m = e.E;
  for (n = 0,
  o = i; 16 > n; n++,
  o += 4) {
      h[n] = t[o] << 24 | t[o + 1] << 16 | t[o + 2] << 8 | t[o + 3] << 0
  }
  for (n = 16; 80 > n; n++) {
      h[n] = rotateLeft(h[n - 3] ^ h[n - 8] ^ h[n - 14] ^ h[n - 16], 1)
  }
  var g;
  for (r = 0; 20 > r; r++) {
      g = rotateLeft(u, 5) + (c & p | ~c & f) + m + h[r] + s & 4294967295,
      m = f,
      f = p,
      p = rotateLeft(c, 30),
      c = u,
      u = g
  }
  for (r = 20; 40 > r; r++) {
      g = rotateLeft(u, 5) + (c ^ p ^ f) + m + h[r] + a & 4294967295,
      m = f,
      f = p,
      p = rotateLeft(c, 30),
      c = u,
      u = g
  }
  for (r = 40; 60 > r; r++) {
      g = rotateLeft(u, 5) + (c & p | c & f | p & f) + m + h[r] + l & 4294967295,
      m = f,
      f = p,
      p = rotateLeft(c, 30),
      c = u,
      u = g
  }
  for (r = 60; 80 > r; r++) {
      g = rotateLeft(u, 5) + (c ^ p ^ f) + m + h[r] + d & 4294967295,
      m = f,
      f = p,
      p = rotateLeft(c, 30),
      c = u,
      u = g
  }
  e.A = e.A + u & 4294967295,
  e.B = e.B + c & 4294967295,
  e.C = e.C + p & 4294967295,
  e.D = e.D + f & 4294967295,
  e.E = e.E + m & 4294967295
}
function rotateLeft(e, t) {
  var i = e >>> 32 - t
    , r = (1 << 32 - t) - 1
    , n = e & r;
  return n << t | i
}
function hexStringToMP(e) {
  var t, i, r = Math.ceil(e.length / 4), n = new JSMPnumber;
  for (n.size = r,
  t = 0; r > t; t++) {
      i = e.substr(4 * t, 4),
      n.data[r - 1 - t] = parseInt(i, 16)
  }
  return n
}
function duplicateMP(e) {
  var t = new JSMPnumber;
  return t.size = e.size,
  t.data = e.data.slice(0),
  t
}
function mpToByteArray(e) {
  var t = []
    , i = 0
    , r = e.size;
  for (i = 0; r > i; i++) {
      t[2 * i] = 255 & e.data[i];
      var n = e.data[i] >>> 8;
      t[2 * i + 1] = n
  }
  return t
}
function byteArrayToBase64(e) {
  var t, i, r = e.length, n = "";
  for (t = r - 3; t >= 0; t -= 3) {
      i = e[t] | e[t + 1] << 8 | e[t + 2] << 16,
      n += base64Encode(i, 4)
  }
  var o = r % 3;
  for (i = 0,
  t += 2; t >= 0; t--) {
      i = i << 8 | e[t]
  }
  return 1 == o ? n = n + base64Encode(i << 16, 2) + "==" : 2 == o && (n = n + base64Encode(i << 8, 3) + "="),
  n
}
function base64Encode(e, t) {
  var i, r = "";
  for (i = t; 4 > i; i++) {
      e >>= 6
  }
  for (i = 0; t > i; i++) {
      r = mapByteToBase64(63 & e) + r,
      e >>= 6
  }
  return r
}
function mapByteToBase64(e) {
  return e >= 0 && 26 > e ? String.fromCharCode(65 + e) : e >= 26 && 52 > e ? String.fromCharCode(97 + e - 26) : e >= 52 && 62 > e ? String.fromCharCode(48 + e - 52) : 62 == e ? "+" : "/"
}

var Key = "e=10001;m=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"
var randomNum = "AA278C7C00D44877AA95055BB0497A6169195B7B79C664E0AC9DFDCE1112CE28282BAA83D5CD95041CB512CD35624CCD6FD873C98579E4D3C4D25E5E6134F65628BDA9DE9C00A6E53A0194EA7483BCB1AABD8AA983282259E2953CC8705D36BB9936E57E"

console.log(Encrypt(null, "1234", "saproof"))
```

```
Example output from above code
V2loAc3ik+qXTJMVF/V/0yKdbQeKGqO7UIA82cqafWUPJ6ALYd/6Bwb9QFsJOEC+yKfwqu5YE36+J3Dpsuk14EQG4YktFVao5D2i5C/2Akm5i1WhPDMbHUFfUJtxbQ3Ldc0jgpMpOrhuEkQ/u9MUgL3l1tL08GTvl4KdnvW2delt1HpuyGFI11WNb5/xXbzmZvRsF2fc3tNpZCvHSTCEQuMOzsQSTeghttXEBFFvmqC9fwH+KjiBGwl11zyH+shv8kYi+LRaqN2LoVz4eFMmWDJ0PNNeA7Aq+mQ/9BIY+tz7Tzz51OSlCgajsPnJbxyHiURdUrc103oKdja8Vd9dnw==
```

The main function here is `Encrypt()`. My program is written in Python. I tried encrypting my OTP using Python's `rsa` module but to no avail. The API rejected the request and marked the encrypted OTP as invalid.

```py
import rsa
import base64

Key = "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"

encrypted = rsa.encrypt(b'1234', rsa.PublicKey(int(Key, 16), 65537))

b64encrypted = base64.b64encode(encrypted)

print(b64encrypted.decode('utf-8'))
```

So my question is, how can I use Microsoft's encryption function in Python? Do I need to manually translate the code myself, or maybe I am doing something wrong with `rsa` module?

Thanks for help.

Comment: *I'm gonna keep this short and clean...*  followed by 425 lines of dense, uncommented, single-letter variable javascript code. For me that's too much code to reverse engineer. I would recommend you find some way to make this a more *minimal* reproducible example.

Comment: It's the official code from Microsoft, originally it was 2K+ lines. I only left the functions that are used by `Encrypt` function. I do not really understand their code, it's complicated to say the least but I will update my post with more detailed information that I had gathered throughout the process. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript code uses [RSA with OAEP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.1) as padding and SHA-1 for both digests (see `applyPKCSv2Padding()`). In addition, the plaintext is encoded with UTF-16LE (see `PackageSADataForProof()`) and the ciphertext is encoded in little endian order (see `byteArrayToBase64()`).

The *RSA* library used does not support OAEP, see [issue #68](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/python-rsa/issues/68). A possible library that supports OAEP is *PyCryptodome* and a possible implementation that is functionally identical to the JavaScript code is (strictly speaking, this applies only to plaintexts up to 214 bytes, for longer ones see the next section):

```py
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import base64

modulusHex = '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';
pubExpHex = '010001'
plaintextStr = '1234'

modulus = int(modulusHex, 16)
pubExp = int(pubExpHex, 16)
plaintext = plaintextStr.encode('utf-16le')                    # encode plaintext with UTF-16LE

publicKey = RSA.construct((modulus, pubExp))   
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(publicKey)                             # apply OAEP as padding
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)      
ciphertextReversed = ciphertext[::-1]                          # encode ciphertext in little endian order
ciphertextReversedB64 = base64.b64encode(ciphertextReversed)
print(ciphertextReversedB64)
```

Note that OAEP is not deterministic, i.e. repeated encryption with the same key and plaintext gives different ciphertexts. Therefore, the implementation cannot be verified by comparing the ciphertexts, but only by a successful decryption (see the last section).

---

**Plaintexts, larger than 214 bytes:** The posted JavaScript code implements a rather unusual feature: RSA can only encrypt plaintexts whose maximum length is equal to the key length (here 2048 bits = 256 bytes) minus the space required by the padding (here for OAEP with SHA-1: 42 bytes), i.e. the maximum length here is 256 - 42 = 214 bytes, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100).
But the Java Script code posted here splits the plaintext into blocks of 214 bytes (or less in the case of the last block), encrypts each block separately and concatenates the ciphertexts. This allows encryption of arbitrarily long plaintexts.
The Python code snippet above does not take this into account, since it is not needed for the short plaintext `1234` used in the example. But for plaintexts larger than 214 bytes this has to be added.

Note that usually long plaintexts are not encrypted this way, but with [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), in which e.g. RSA is combined with AES: The plaintext is encrypted with AES, the AES key with RSA.

---

**Test:** The JavaScript code below decrypts a ciphertext generated with the JavaScript code posted in the question and a ciphertext generated with the Python code posted in this answer.
Result: Both ciphertexts can be decrypted with the *same* logic, which shows that the JavaScript and Python encryption code are functionally identical.

Note that a new key pair was used for this test, since only the public key was posted in the question, and that the public key of this new key pair must be applied when generating the ciphertexts (see JavaScript code for encryption) so that the private key used in decryption matches.

```js
(async () => {

function Encrypt(e, t, i, r) {
  var n = [];
  switch (i.toLowerCase()) {
  case "saproof":
      if (null == t) {
          return null
      }
      n = PackageSADataForProof(t);
      break;
  case "newpwd":
      if (null == r) {
          return null
      }
  }
  if (null == n || "undefined" == typeof n) {
      return n
  }
  if ("undefined" != typeof Key && void 0 !== parseRSAKeyFromString) {
      var o = parseRSAKeyFromString(Key)
  }
  var s = RSAEncrypt(n, o, randomNum);
  return s
}

function PackageSADataForProof(e) {
  var t, i = [], r = 0;
  for (t = 0; t < e.length; t++) {
      i[r++] = 127 & e.charCodeAt(t),
      i[r++] = (65280 & e.charCodeAt(t)) >> 8
  }
  return i
}

function parseRSAKeyFromString(e) {
  var t = e.indexOf(";");
  if (0 > t) {
      return null
  }
  var i = e.substr(0, t)
    , r = e.substr(t + 1)
    , n = i.indexOf("=");
  if (0 > n) {
      return null
  }
  var o = i.substr(n + 1);
  if (n = r.indexOf("="),
  0 > n) {
      return null
  }
  var s = r.substr(n + 1)
    , a = new Object;
  return a.n = hexStringToMP(s),
  a.e = parseInt(o, 16),
  a
}

function hexStringToMP(e) {
  var t, i, r = Math.ceil(e.length / 4), n = new JSMPnumber;
  for (n.size = r,
  t = 0; r > t; t++) {
      i = e.substr(4 * t, 4),
      n.data[r - 1 - t] = parseInt(i, 16)
  }
  return n
}

function RSAEncrypt(e, t) {
  for (var i = [], r = 42, n = 2 * t.n.size - r, o = 0; o < e.length; o += n) {
      if (o + n >= e.length) {
          var s = RSAEncryptBlock(e.slice(o), t, randomNum);
          s && (i = s.concat(i))
      } else {
          var s = RSAEncryptBlock(e.slice(o, o + n), t, randomNum);
          s && (i = s.concat(i))
      }
  }
  var a = byteArrayToBase64(i);
  return a
}

function RSAEncryptBlock(e, t, i) {
  var r = t.n
    , n = t.e
    , o = e.length
    , s = 2 * r.size
    , a = 42;
  if (o + a > s) {
      return null
  }
  applyPKCSv2Padding(e, s, i),
  e = e.reverse();
  var l = byteArrayToMP(e)
    , d = modularExp(l, n, r);
  d.size = r.size;
  var h = mpToByteArray(d);
  return h = h.reverse()
}

function JSMPnumber() {
  this.size = 1,
  this.data = [],
  this.data[0] = 0
}

function byteArrayToMP(e) {
  var t = new JSMPnumber
    , i = 0
    , r = e.length
    , n = r >> 1;
  for (i = 0; n > i; i++) {
      t.data[i] = e[2 * i] + (e[1 + 2 * i] << 8)
  }
  return r % 2 && (t.data[i++] = e[r - 1]),
  t.size = i,
  t
}

function modularExp(e, t, i) {
  for (var r = [], n = 0; t > 0; ) {
      r[n] = 1 & t,
      t >>>= 1,
      n++
  }
  for (var o = duplicateMP(e), s = n - 2; s >= 0; s--) {
      o = modularMultiply(o, o, i),
      1 == r[s] && (o = modularMultiply(o, e, i))
  }
  return o
}
function modularMultiply(e, t, i) {
  var r = multiplyMP(e, t)
    , n = divideMP(r, i);
  return n.r
}
function multiplyMP(e, t) {
  var i = new JSMPnumber;
  i.size = e.size + t.size;
  var r, n;
  for (r = 0; r < i.size; r++) {
      i.data[r] = 0
  }
  var o = e.data
    , s = t.data
    , a = i.data;
  if (e == t) {
      for (r = 0; r < e.size; r++) {
          a[2 * r] += o[r] * o[r]
      }
      for (r = 1; r < e.size; r++) {
          for (n = 0; r > n; n++) {
              a[r + n] += 2 * o[r] * o[n]
          }
      }
  } else {
      for (r = 0; r < e.size; r++) {
          for (n = 0; n < t.size; n++) {
              a[r + n] += o[r] * s[n]
          }
      }
  }
  return normalizeJSMP(i),
  i
}
function normalizeJSMP(e) {
  var t, i, r, n, o;
  for (r = e.size,
  i = 0,
  t = 0; r > t; t++) {
      n = e.data[t],
      n += i,
      o = n,
      i = Math.floor(n / 65536),
      n -= 65536 * i,
      e.data[t] = n
  }
}
function removeLeadingZeroes(e) {
  for (var t = e.size - 1; t > 0 && 0 == e.data[t--]; ) {
      e.size--
  }
}
function divideMP(e, t) {
  var i = e.size
    , r = t.size
    , n = t.data[r - 1]
    , o = t.data[r - 1] + t.data[r - 2] / 65536
    , s = new JSMPnumber;
  s.size = i - r + 1,
  e.data[i] = 0;
  for (var a = i - 1; a >= r - 1; a--) {
      var l = a - r + 1
        , d = Math.floor((65536 * e.data[a + 1] + e.data[a]) / o);
      if (d > 0) {
          var h = multiplyAndSubtract(e, d, t, l);
          for (0 > h && (d--,
          multiplyAndSubtract(e, d, t, l)); h > 0 && e.data[a] >= n; ) {
              h = multiplyAndSubtract(e, 1, t, l),
              h > 0 && d++
          }
      }
      s.data[l] = d
  }
  removeLeadingZeroes(e);
  var u = {
      "q": s,
      "r": e
  };
  return u
}
function multiplyAndSubtract(e, t, i, r) {
  var n, o = e.data.slice(0), s = 0, a = e.data;
  for (n = 0; n < i.size; n++) {
      var l = s + i.data[n] * t;
      s = l >>> 16,
      l -= 65536 * s,
      l > a[n + r] ? (a[n + r] += 65536 - l,
      s++) : a[n + r] -= l
  }
  return s > 0 && (a[n + r] -= s),
  a[n + r] < 0 ? (e.data = o.slice(0),
  -1) : 1
}
function applyPKCSv2Padding(e, t, i) {
  var r, n = e.length, o = [218, 57, 163, 238, 94, 107, 75, 13, 50, 85, 191, 239, 149, 96, 24, 144, 175, 216, 7, 9], s = t - n - 40 - 2, a = [];
  for (r = 0; s > r; r++) {
      a[r] = 0
  }
  a[s] = 1;
  var l = o.concat(a, e)
    , d = [];
  for (r = 0; 20 > r; r++) {
      d[r] = Math.floor(256 * Math.random())
  }
  d = SHA1(d.concat(i));
  var h = MGF(d, t - 21)
    , u = XORarrays(l, h)
    , c = MGF(u, 20)
    , p = XORarrays(d, c)
    , f = [];
  for (f[0] = 0,
  f = f.concat(p, u),
  r = 0; r < f.length; r++) {
      e[r] = f[r]
  }
}
function MGF(e, t) {
  if (t > 4096) {
      return null
  }
  var i = e.slice(0)
    , r = i.length;
  i[r++] = 0,
  i[r++] = 0,
  i[r++] = 0,
  i[r] = 0;
  for (var n = 0, o = []; o.length < t; ) {
      i[r] = n++,
      o = o.concat(SHA1(i))
  }
  return o.slice(0, t)
}
function XORarrays(e, t) {
  if (e.length != t.length) {
      return null
  }
  for (var i = [], r = e.length, n = 0; r > n; n++) {
      i[n] = e[n] ^ t[n]
  }
  return i
}
function SHA1(e) {
  var t, i = e.slice(0);
  PadSHA1Input(i);
  var r = {
      "A": 1732584193,
      "B": 4023233417,
      "C": 2562383102,
      "D": 271733878,
      "E": 3285377520
  };
  for (t = 0; t < i.length; t += 64) {
      SHA1RoundFunction(r, i, t)
  }
  var n = [];
  return wordToBytes(r.A, n, 0),
  wordToBytes(r.B, n, 4),
  wordToBytes(r.C, n, 8),
  wordToBytes(r.D, n, 12),
  wordToBytes(r.E, n, 16),
  n
}
function wordToBytes(e, t, i) {
  var r;
  for (r = 3; r >= 0; r--) {
      t[i + r] = 255 & e,
      e >>>= 8
  }
}
function PadSHA1Input(e) {
  var t, i = e.length, r = i, n = i % 64, o = 55 > n ? 56 : 120;
  for (e[r++] = 128,
  t = n + 1; o > t; t++) {
      e[r++] = 0
  }
  var s = 8 * i;
  for (t = 1; 8 > t; t++) {
      e[r + 8 - t] = 255 & s,
      s >>>= 8
  }
}

function SHA1RoundFunction(e, t, i) {
  var r, n, o, s = 1518500249, a = 1859775393, l = 2400959708, d = 3395469782, h = [], u = e.A, c = e.B, p = e.C, f = e.D, m = e.E;
  for (n = 0,
  o = i; 16 > n; n++,
  o += 4) {
      h[n] = t[o] << 24 | t[o + 1] << 16 | t[o + 2] << 8 | t[o + 3] << 0
  }
  for (n = 16; 80 > n; n++) {
      h[n] = rotateLeft(h[n - 3] ^ h[n - 8] ^ h[n - 14] ^ h[n - 16], 1)
  }
  var g;
  for (r = 0; 20 > r; r++) {
      g = rotateLeft(u, 5) + (c & p | ~c & f) + m + h[r] + s & 4294967295,
      m = f,
      f = p,
      p = rotateLeft(c, 30),
      c = u,
      u = g
  }
  for (r = 20; 40 > r; r++) {
      g = rotateLeft(u, 5) + (c ^ p ^ f) + m + h[r] + a & 4294967295,
      m = f,
      f = p,
      p = rotateLeft(c, 30),
      c = u,
      u = g
  }
  for (r = 40; 60 > r; r++) {
      g = rotateLeft(u, 5) + (c & p | c & f | p & f) + m + h[r] + l & 4294967295,
      m = f,
      f = p,
      p = rotateLeft(c, 30),
      c = u,
      u = g
  }
  for (r = 60; 80 > r; r++) {
      g = rotateLeft(u, 5) + (c ^ p ^ f) + m + h[r] + d & 4294967295,
      m = f,
      f = p,
      p = rotateLeft(c, 30),
      c = u,
      u = g
  }
  e.A = e.A + u & 4294967295,
  e.B = e.B + c & 4294967295,
  e.C = e.C + p & 4294967295,
  e.D = e.D + f & 4294967295,
  e.E = e.E + m & 4294967295
}
function rotateLeft(e, t) {
  var i = e >>> 32 - t
    , r = (1 << 32 - t) - 1
    , n = e & r;
  return n << t | i
}
function hexStringToMP(e) {
  var t, i, r = Math.ceil(e.length / 4), n = new JSMPnumber;
  for (n.size = r,
  t = 0; r > t; t++) {
      i = e.substr(4 * t, 4),
      n.data[r - 1 - t] = parseInt(i, 16)
  }
  return n
}
function duplicateMP(e) {
  var t = new JSMPnumber;
  return t.size = e.size,
  t.data = e.data.slice(0),
  t
}
function mpToByteArray(e) {
  var t = []
    , i = 0
    , r = e.size;
  for (i = 0; r > i; i++) {
      t[2 * i] = 255 & e.data[i];
      var n = e.data[i] >>> 8;
      t[2 * i + 1] = n
  }
  return t
}
function byteArrayToBase64(e) {
  var t, i, r = e.length, n = "";
  for (t = r - 3; t >= 0; t -= 3) {
      i = e[t] | e[t + 1] << 8 | e[t + 2] << 16,
      n += base64Encode(i, 4)
  }
  var o = r % 3;
  for (i = 0,
  t += 2; t >= 0; t--) {
      i = i << 8 | e[t]
  }
  return 1 == o ? n = n + base64Encode(i << 16, 2) + "==" : 2 == o && (n = n + base64Encode(i << 8, 3) + "="),
  n
}
function base64Encode(e, t) {
  var i, r = "";
  for (i = t; 4 > i; i++) {
      e >>= 6
  }
  for (i = 0; t > i; i++) {
      r = mapByteToBase64(63 & e) + r,
      e >>= 6
  }
  return r
}
function mapByteToBase64(e) {
  return e >= 0 && 26 > e ? String.fromCharCode(65 + e) : e >= 26 && 52 > e ? String.fromCharCode(97 + e - 26) : e >= 52 && 62 > e ? String.fromCharCode(48 + e - 52) : 62 == e ? "+" : "/"
}

var Key = "e=10001;m=ba71796836ba1c27cb30c23f3192d3e610e4df4e0253eca914c162063a3041d50c40a60767e7e4941ec6a4bc426adc5827f859eeb8df1c7dca96adb4fd8d446d80d1a29c9349f92b4f33f3c2c5f852bfe5db90ad75095d847093320c1ffc4bff6ee04da1b7f375913e0e176fe654302ad8c8e379432af022e6411eb764c5c1f25c26b06244978470b7d58164d7191427ee09e058aca452ee6b4bcdde014d711fd14ba2341fca26bcf7f13292238eeffdd45b077e3004d9f472e34b1dbf2dfde0da3afcd5e89f12660396b8bf399a783a166efb4068d4b5e5a024defaf9884366025fb11ab543aec9032dd95c31e2e57e77f0370cfe8fb4c1812a917c4ade221b"
var randomNum = "AA278C7C00D44877AA95055BB0497A6169195B7B79C664E0AC9DFDCE1112CE28282BAA83D5CD95041CB512CD35624CCD6FD873C98579E4D3C4D25E5E6134F65628BDA9DE9C00A6E53A0194EA7483BCB1AABD8AA983282259E2953CC8705D36BB9936E57E"

var ciphertextB64FromJS = Encrypt(null, "1234", "saproof");
document.getElementById("js_enc").innerHTML = "JavaScript code (encryption): " + ciphertextB64FromJS;

// Decryption ======================================================================================================================================================

// Decryption of a ciphertext from the JavaScript Code 
var decryptedCiphertextFromJS = await decrypt(ciphertextB64FromJS);
document.getElementById("js_dec").innerHTML = "JavaScript code (decryption): " + decryptedCiphertextFromJS;

// Decryption of a ciphertext from the Python code for encryption 
var ciphertextB64FromPy = 'iQefWJtEXRjMpJj59NmODmDVuJJkmsSV2pNvPrAX74lDWiXHjY4H34XAEGHY5bJ/3xJ3f7pM1R0Nb8cBJSgQMpCO/0PCdDSbalw7M/cbEEOzrIVMxg8NXOsUM6tqetaroSAutyesg8+EsP4liow3ssV6I7cX/QDpunFV0vRHxTM9Am35QNrNfpvZMu4kV642dq9ocSJLdbaBfaKXUyBA6nYzUIhq3nHx8XzPxo9DnAoE6qkGeRpQzV7Mo+jeY26YOP/DyVmb0JuOXPI8Uz/4yxhQp7ygAVOF5CNojZN0XtZVqORV4+2bFEMD+Fi9YIIFFMrym169ACoy2faTfLYjlw=='; // MAKE SURE TO USE THE CORRECT PUBLIC KEY DURING ENCRYPTION!!!: modulus = 0xba717968..., public exponent = 0x10001 (s. above)
var decryptedCiphertextFromPy = await decrypt(ciphertextB64FromPy);
document.getElementById("py_dec").innerHTML = "Python code (decryption): " + decryptedCiphertextFromPy;

async function decrypt(ciphertextBase64){
    var pkcs8Der = b642ab('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');
    var privateKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("pkcs8", pkcs8Der, {name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: "SHA-1"}, true, ["decrypt"]);   
    var ciphertext = b642ab(ciphertextBase64);
    ciphertext = ciphertext.reverse();                                                              // reverse little endian order
    var decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({name: "RSA-OAEP"}, privateKey, ciphertext); // apply OAEP as padding 
    return decodeUTF16LE(decrypted);                                                                // decode with UTF-16LE 
}

// Helper
function b642ab(base64_string){
    return Uint8Array.from(window.atob(base64_string), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
}
  
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/14601808
function decodeUTF16LE(buf) {
    var cp = [];
    var binaryStr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
    for( var i = 0; i < binaryStr.length; i+=2) {
        cp.push( 
            binaryStr.charCodeAt(i) |
            ( binaryStr.charCodeAt(i+1) << 8 )
        );
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply( String, cp );
}

})();
```

```html
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="js_enc"></p>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="js_dec"></p>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="py_dec"></p>
```

Comment: I'm deeply sorry about the delay, I somehow completely missed your answer. I just tested it and it works perfectly, and I'd like to leave you a tip from your phenomenal help. Do you use cryptocurrency by any chance? If so, please leave your BTC or ETH wallet address in the comment. Thank you for your help again, it means a lot to me. @Topaco